# mcq power series expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-\frac{1}{2})(x-1)}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Let $\forall |x|<\dfrac{1}{2},\quad  f(x)=\dfrac{1}{(x-\frac{1}{2})(x-1)}$, $f$   has power series expansion

1. $\sum_{n\geq 0}(2^{n+2}-2)x^n $
2. $\sum_{n\geq 0}(2^n-2)x^n$
3. $\sum_{n\geq 0}(2^n-1)x^n $

note that $\dfrac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^{n}$

if  $| x| < 1/2 \implies   | 2x|< 1$ and $|x|<1$ then :

\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= -\dfrac{2}{(x - 1/2)} + \dfrac{2}{(x-1)}\\ 
f(x)&= \dfrac{4}{( 1 - 2x)} -\dfrac{2}{(1-x)}\\ 
f(x)&=\sum_{n\geq 0}{ 4 (2x)^n -2 (x)^n }\\
f(x)&=\sum_{n\geq 0} { [ 2^{n+2} -2 ] . x^n } 
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(0)=2$. For (1) the series evaluates to $2$ at zero. For (2) this is $-1$ and for (3) we obtain $0$. Hence (2) and (3) can't be correct.